# AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC "error":"invalid_request"

Tags: dotnetopenauth

At the second call to `Client.ProcessUserAuthorization();` after I get the code from the oauth server, I get an exception:  `Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.`

Here is the last part from the log file taken with log4net, the full log is recorded in this gist: https://gist.github.com/tonyeung/5513769

```
2013-05-03 15:14:41,292 (GMT-5) [10] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC request.
2013-05-03 15:14:41,393 (GMT-5) [10] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST http://localhost:38828/OAuth/Token
2013-05-03 15:14:41,450 (GMT-5) [10] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Http - http://localhost:38828/OAuth/Token returned 400 BadRequest: Bad Request
2013-05-03 15:14:41,450 (GMT-5) [10] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - WebException from http://localhost:38828/OAuth/Token: 
{"error":"invalid_request"}
```

I've uploaded the solution to https://github.com/tonyeung/dotnetopenauth
The entry point is in the about action on the home controller of the Client project.
The solution is in VS2012, the latest nuget dnoa package. Nuget restore is on.

Please note that I'm implementing pieces as I need them in order to understand how the library works. I'm sure that this error is due to a missing implementation somewhere, but I'm not sure what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I was missing implementations for IsAuthorizationValid and CreateAccessToken in the Authorization Server. Please check the github repository for the stubs i put in that makes the error go away.

EDIT:
There was also a database validation error that I didn't trap. So basically any error on the server side will cause this message it looks like.

EDIT2:
There was also an issue where if the url of the page contains any non url encoded values it will throw an invalid request. In my case, my login page had a querystring parameter of returnUrl, and I had set it to /Home, which it DID NOT like, had to be: %2FHome